# Minimum rearrangment of boxes to accomodate new box in cartons

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming, linear-programming, greedy

There are `n cartons`. Each carton can have some boxes in it. Each box occupies some space.

We are given the free space left in each carton and the list of sizes of boxes in each carton. There is no restriction on number/size of boxes in each carton.

Now we have a new box, with `size x`, which needs to be accomodated in any one of the cartons.
**Rearrangement of any number of boxes from a carton to any other carton is allowed, provided the new carton has the space left to accomodate the rearranged box.**

I need to find the rearrangement that can be obtained in the least no of box movements & can accomodate the new box.

**I am more interested in the case that the new box cannot be accomodated in any free-space of any carton and some rearrangement is mandatory to make room for the new box.**

```
Input format
x : size of new box
n : no of cartons
    box_no_1 :: free_space, no_of_boxes, box1_size, box2_size, ...
    box_no_2 :: free_space, no_of_boxes, box1_size, box2_size, ...

example:
x : 60
n : 3
    1 :: 10 , 3, 10 , 10 , 30
    2 :: 20 , 2, 20 , 10
    3 :: 50, 3, 10, 30, 20

Answer:: box with size 10 in carton 3 can be moved to carton 1. 
Then new box can be kept in box 3.
```

Can someone tell me how to solve this problem ?

Comment: What did you try? Are you aware of the bin-packing problem? This looks like it's easily tackled by integer-programming using the classic formulation including an objective, which describes the sum of unmoved boxes (maximization).

Comment: @sascha  My problem is a bit different than the bin-packing problem. Assume that free space is not available anywhere to accommodate the new box. The only option is to do some rearrangements of current boxes to make free space available.

I might have misunderstood your suggestion. Could you please give an example of using bin-packing in the provided input

Comment: Try to understand the integer-programming formulation to modify it to your needs (it will result in an feasibility problem without an objective). Than add an objective which equals to keeping old positions. Presenting such a task usually includes own attempts and ideas and what went wrong. You have to try something.